# Zip file transfer using akka

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to AKKA (I am using java). I am not able to figure out how to transfer a zip file to remote actors. Should i use akka-http?
I tried going through akka-streams but i could not understand how to transfer a binary file to remote actors.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed using akka-http could be a nice way to decouple the various systems from each other.

akka-streams is mainly used to stream data within a system, and connects to 'external' systems with sources and sinks. This of course works best when those sources and sinks also support streaming and backpressure. The akka-http client and server indeed support streaming and backpressure, so they could be a good candidate ;).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. mean while i also found some comments in some forums that it is not so good to transfer files using akka, any thoughts on this?